# Nuxt 2 Composition API: Method Type 'unknown' Error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm working on a Nuxt 2 project with the Nuxt 2 Composition API plugin and TypeScript. I've encountered a type error with one of my methods, handleRemoveImage, which is causing the error: '__VLS_ctx.handleRemoveImage' is of type 'unknown'.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, computed, useRoute } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
    setup(_, context) {
        const uploadedImages = ref<string[]>([]);

        const handleRemoveImage = (index: number) => {
            uploadedImages.value.splice(index, 1);
        };

        return {
            handleRemoveImage,
            uploadedImages,
            // ... other returned properties
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

This method is used in my template like this:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(image, index) in uploadedImages" :key="index">
        <!-- ... other HTML elements ... -->
        <button @click="handleRemoveImage(index)">Remove Image</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring as the method seems to be correctly typed and used. Has anyone encountered this issue before or could suggest what might be going wrong here?. Just for the sake of more context I'm using VSC with Volar (I have read that there might be IDE implications related to configuration that might trigger this issues but can't find a specific one).